# Programmatically generate orders

Tags: 8, ubercart

I am trying to programmatically generate orders in Drupal 8.

```php
$order = Order::create(array(
  'uid' => $uid,
  'order_status' => uc_order_state_default('in_checkout'),
));
$order->save();
$product = Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('uc_order_product')->create(array(
  'qty' => 1,
  'order_id' => $order->id(),
  'nid' => $product_nid,
  'title' => $product_node->get('title')->value,
  'model' => '1001',
  'cost' => $product_node->get('display_price')->value,
));

$product->save(); 
uc_order_product_save($order->id(), $product);
$order->save();
```

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong? Do I need to extend to some class in particular? This order is not generated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding these to my file:

```
//for order
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\uc_order\Entity\Order;
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;
//for products
use Drupal\uc_order\EditableOrderPanePluginBase;
use Drupal\uc_order\Entity\OrderProduct;
use Drupal\uc_order\OrderInterface;
```